# The message "Error: 'results.json' not found. " pops up and can't find the reason

Tags: json, gekko

I am trying to use Gekko package to solve non-linear equaions. And I made the code for my problem and it worked. But when I changed some variables, in this case t(time), F2, theta1.
Then suddenly "Error: 'results.json' not found. " pops up and I can't find the solution.

I tried to use different iMode but it still didn't work.

Here is the my function

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

m.time=np.linspace(0.046875,0.328125,5000)
#Variables
xc0 = 0 # Initial center of mass
yc0 = 0 # center = 0 unit: m
k3_ratio= 1.0 # stiffness center 0= 1
strightness = 0e-6 # Straightness error
x_p = m.Var(0) # pole of rotation
y_p = m.Var(0.5*(1-k3_ratio)/(1+k3_ratio))
# w/2*(k1-k3)/(k1+k3) intial stiffness center
theta = m.Var(value=0) # yawing angle
x_c = m.Var(xc0) # Centor of mass
y_c = m.Var(yc0)
a = m.Var(0) #x_p.dt()
b = m.Var(0) #y_p.dt()
z = m.Var(0) #theta.dt()
ac = m.Var(0) #x_c.dt()
bc = m.Var(0) #y_c.dt()
t = m.Param(m.time) #Time
R1 = m.Var() # Reaction forces
R2 = m.Var()
R3 = m.Var()
R4 = m.Var()
tau1 = m.Param()
tau2 = m.Param()
tau3 = m.Param()
tau4 = m.Param()
s1 = m.Param()
s2 = m.Param()
s3 = m.Param()
s4 = m.Param()



theta5 = m.Param() #cam angle


theta1 = m.Var() #input 1
theta3 = m.Var() #output 1

A = m.Var()
B = m.Var()
C = m.Var()
K = m.Var()


theta11 = m.Param() #input 2(second structure)
theta33 = m.Var() #output 2

AA = m.Var()
BB = m.Var()
CC = m.Var()
KK = m.Var()

theta333 = m.Var() #Velocity of output
theta3333 = m.Var() #acceleration of output

d = m.Var() #offset ratio
d2 = -0.060904 #center of mass
d3 = 31.521 #y force

F = m.Param() #gravity force
F2 = m.Param() #y_cam
F3 = m.Param() #x_cam

#constants
h = 3.78/180*math.pi #arm 각도범위
beta = 45/360*2*math.pi #cam 할부각

r1 = 379 #length of link1
r2 = 188 #length of link2
r3 = 70 #length of link3
r0 = 486.6 #length of link0

r11 = 140
r22 = 519.299
r33 = 58
r00 = 526.647

#constants
l = 0.233 # m, Length of a platform
q = l # m
w = 0.119 # m, Width of a platform

mu = 0.02 # friction coefficient
g = 9.8 # gravity acceleration
k1 = 2.5e8 # N/m 20:2.5e8, 35L:4.95e8,
k2 = k1
k3 = k1 *k3_ratio
k4 = k3
mass = l*w*0.012*2790 #kg


theta0 = 22.728/360*2*math.pi


theta5 = 2*math.pi/3*t 


theta00 = 80.418/360*2*math.pi

theta11 = theta3 + math.pi

c1 = 10 #damping coefficient
c2 = c1
c3 = c1 *k3_ratio
c4 = c3

tau1 = m.abs(m.atan((w/2-y_p)/(x_p+l/2)))
tau2 = m.abs(m.atan((w/2-y_p)/(l/2-x_p)))
tau3 = m.abs(m.atan((y_p+w/2)/(x_p+q/2)))
tau4 = m.abs(m.atan((y_p+w/2)/(q/2-x_p)))
s1 = m.sqrt((l/2+x_p)**2 + (w/2-y_p)**2)
s2 = m.sqrt((l/2-x_p)**2 + (w/2-y_p)**2)
s3 = m.sqrt((q/2+x_p)**2 + (w/2+y_p)**2)
s4 = m.sqrt((q/2-x_p)**2 + (w/2+y_p)**2)

m.Equation(theta1 == -1.89/180*math.pi+h*(0.28005+0.43989*theta5/beta-0.315055*m.cos(4*math.pi/3*theta5/beta-math.pi/6)))

m.Equation(A == 2*r0*r3*m.cos(theta0)-2*r1*r3*m.cos(theta1))
m.Equation(B == 2*r0*r3*m.sin(theta0)-2*r1*r3*m.sin(theta1))
m.Equation(C == r0**2+r1**2+r3**2-r2**2-2*r0*r1*(m.cos(theta0)*m.cos(theta1)+m.sin(theta0)*m.sin(theta1)))

m.Equation(K == (-B-(B**2-C**2+A**2)**(1/2))/(C-A))
m.Equation(theta3 == m.atan(K)*2)


m.Equation(AA == 2*r00*r33*m.cos(theta00)-2*r11*r33*m.cos(theta11))
m.Equation(BB == 2*r00*r33*m.sin(theta00)-2*r11*r33*m.sin(theta11))
m.Equation(CC == r00**2+r11**2+r33**2-r22**2-2*r00*r11*(m.cos(theta00)*m.cos(theta11)+m.sin(theta00)*m.sin(theta11)))

m.Equation(KK == (-BB+(BB**2-CC**2+AA**2)**(1/2))/(CC-AA))
m.Equation(theta33 == m.atan(KK)*2)

m.Equation(theta333 == theta33.dt())
m.Equation(theta3333 == theta333.dt())


m.Equation(d == 0.145209 - m.cos(theta33)*0.116)

 

F = (mass)*g #gravity force
F2 = m.if2(t-0.125, (mass)*g*0.7, 0) #y_force
F3 = (mass)*g*0.7 #x_force


# Reaction force
m.Equations([z == theta.dt(), a== x_p.dt()
, b== y_p.dt()])
m.Equations([ac== x_c.dt(), bc== y_c.dt()])
m.Equation(R1 == k1*theta*m.cos(theta/2+m.atan((w/2\
-y_p)/(l/2+x_p)))*m.sqrt((l/2+x_p)**2+(w/2-y_p)**2)+\
c1 *(z*m.cos(theta/2+m.atan((w/2-y_p)\
/(l/w+x_p)))*m.sqrt((l/2+x_p)**2+(w/2-y_p)**2) -\
theta*(z/2-((w/2-y_p)*x_p.dt()) / \
((((w/2-y_p)/(l/2+x_p))**2+1)*(l/2+x_p)**2)-\
(y_p.dt())/((((w/2-y_p)/(l/2+x_p))**2 +1)*(l/2\
+ x_p)) )*m.sin(theta/2 +m.atan((w/2-y_p)/(l/2+ \
x_p)/(l/2 +x_p)))*m.sqrt((l/2+x_p)**2 + (w/2-y_p)**2)\
+ theta*m.cos(theta/2+m.atan((w/2-y_p)/(l/2+x_p)))\
*1/(2*m.sqrt((l/2+x_p)**2 + (w/2-y_p)**2)) \
*((l+2*x_p)*x_p.dt()+(2*y_p-w)*y_p.dt() )))
m.Equation(R2 == k2*theta*m.cos(theta/2-m.atan((w/2-\
y_p)/(l/2-x_p)))*m.sqrt((l/2-x_p)**2+(w/2-y_p)**2) +\
c2 *(z*m.cos(theta/2-m.atan((w/2-y_p)/(l/2-x_p )))\
* m.sqrt((l/2-x_p )**2+(w/2-y_p )**2 )-\
theta*(z/2-((w/2- y_p )*x_p.dt())/((l/2- x_p )**2\
*(((w/2-y_p)/(l/2-x_p ))**2+1))+(y_p.dt())/\
((l/2-x_p)*(((w/2-y_p)/(l/2-x_p ))**2+1)))*\
m.sin(theta/2 - m.atan((w/2-y_p)/(l/2-x_p )))\
*m.sqrt((l/2-x_p)**2+(w/2-y_p)**2)+ \
theta*m.cos(theta/2-m.atan((w/2-y_p)/(l/2-x_p)))\
*1/(2*m.sqrt((l/2-x_p)**2 + (w/2-y_p)**2))\
*((2*x_p-l)*x_p.dt()+(2*y_p- w)*y_p.dt() )))
m.Equation(R3 == k3*theta*m.cos(theta/2-\
m.atan((w/2+y_p)/(q/2+x_p)))*m.sqrt((q/2+x_p)**2\
+(w/2+y_p)**2) +\
c3 *(z*m.cos(theta/2-m.atan((y_p+w/2)/(x_p+q/2)))\
* m.sqrt((q/2+x_p )**2 + (w/2 + y_p )**2)-\
theta*(z/2+((w/2+y_p )*x_p.dt())/((q/2+x_p)**2\
*(((w/2+y_p)/(q/2+x_p))**2+1))-(y_p.dt())/((q/2+
x_p)*(((w/2+y_p)/(q/2+x_p))**2+1)))*\
m.sin(theta/2 - m.atan((w/2+y_p)/(q/2+x_p)))\
*m.sqrt((q/2+x_p)**2+(w/2+y_p)**2)+ \
theta*m.cos(theta/2-m.atan((w/2+y_p)/(q/2+x_p )))\
*(1/(2*m.sqrt((q/2+x_p)**2+(w/2+y_p)**2)))\
*((q +2*x_p)*x_p.dt()+(w+2*y_p )*y_p.dt() )))
m.Equation(R4 == k4*theta*m.cos(theta/2+\
m.atan((w/2+y_p)/(q/2-x_p)))*m.sqrt((q/2-\
x_p)**2+(w/2+y_p)**2) +\
c4*(z*m.cos(theta/2+m.atan((w/2+y_p)/(q/2-x_p)))\
* m.sqrt((q/2-x_p )**2 + (w/2 + y_p )**2 ) - \
theta*(z/2+((w/2+y_p)*x_p.dt())/((q/2-x_p)**2\
*(((w/2+y_p)/(q/2-x_p))**2+1))+(y_p.dt())\
/((q/2-x_p)*(((w/2+y_p)/(q/2-x_p))**2+1)))*\
m.sin(theta/2 + m.atan((w/2+y_p)/(q/2-x_p)))\
*m.sqrt((q/2-x_p)**2+(w/2+y_p)**2)+ \
theta*m.cos(theta/2+m.atan((w/2+y_p)/(q/2-x_p)))\
*(1/(2*m.sqrt((q/2-x_p)**2+(w/2+y_p)**2)))*\
((2*x_p -q)*x_p.dt()+(w+2*y_p)*y_p.dt() )))
m.Equation(x_c == yc0/(w/2)*(-s1*m.cos(tau1+theta)+s2*\
m.cos(tau2-theta)+s3*m.cos(tau3-theta)-s4*\
m.cos(tau4+theta))/4 +\
(4*x_p-s1*m.cos(tau1+theta)+s2*m.cos(tau2-theta)\
-s3*m.cos(tau3-theta)+s4*m.cos(tau4+theta) )/4)
m.Equation(y_c == yc0/(w/2)*( s1*\
m.sin(tau1+theta)+s2*m.sin(tau2-theta)+s3\
*m.sin(tau3-theta)+s4*m.sin(tau4+theta) )/4 +\
(4*y_p+s1*m.sin(tau1+theta)+s2*m.sin(tau2-theta)-\
s3*m.sin(tau3-theta)-s4*m.sin(tau4+theta))/4 )
m.Equation(F3-mu*mass*g-mu*(R1+R2+R3+R4+k4*\
 m.abs(strightness))==mass*a.dt()) # Fx=m*x_p.dt(dt())
m.Equation(-R1+R2-R3+R4-mu*mass*g-k4*\
strightness-F-F2==mass*b.dt()) # Fy=m*y_p.dt(dt())
m.Equation(F3*(d-y_p)-(x_p-mu*y_p+(l+mu*w)/2)*R1 +\
(x_p+mu*y_p-(l+mu*w)/2)*R2 -(x_p-mu*y_p+\
(q-mu*w)/2)*R3 + (x_p+mu*y_p-(q-mu*w)/2)\
*R4+k4*strightness + F*(d2-x_p) + F2*(d3-x_p)== mass*((w**2+l**2)/12+\
(x_p-x_c)**2+(y_p-y_c)**2)*z.dt())
#Mc=I*theta.dt(dt())
m.options.IMODE=6
m.solve(disp=False)
df = pd.DataFrame([m.time, theta.value])
df.to_csv('D:/pyyhon/1축 힘 변화X/yaw angle_middle.csv',\
index=None)
plt.plot(m.time, theta.value)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The message `Error: 'results.json' not found.` is because the solver crashed before finding a solution. I recommend going back to the version that was working and incrementally add the changes until the problem appears. Another approach is to change solvers such as:

```py
m.options.SOLVER=1 # APOPT
m.options.SOLVER=2 # BPOPT
m.options.SOLVER=3 # IPOPT
```

Better initialization can also help the solver find a solution. Some of the solvers may crash when it tries to determine a search direction with `NaN` or when it needs to allocate more RAM than the computer has because of ill-conditioned matrices.

When the solver does not find a solution, the error is different:

```
 Use command apm_get(server,app,'infeasibilities.txt') to retrieve file
 @error: Solution Not Found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 6, in <module>
    m.solve()
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gekko/gekko.py", line 2185, in solve
    raise Exception(response)
Exception:  @error: Solution Not Found
```

Here is a simple case that reproduces the error of no solution found:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Var(lb=1)
m.Equation(x==0)
m.Minimize(x**2)
m.solve()
```

If you get the message `Error: 'results.json' not found.`, it is a solver problem before it could report a good or bad solution.

A few other suggestions:

- Replace `m.abs()` with `m.abs3()` for an absolute value function that has continuous first and second derivates. The discontinuity at 0 is a problem for convergence of gradient-based solvers. Use `m.abs2()` if the APOPT solver isn't working and you need an NLP solver such as IPOPT.
- Add constraints to the arguments of `m.atan()` to help the solver search in a feasible region.
- Try fewer time points initially with something like `m.time=np.linspace(0.047,0.33,10)` and then scale up to higher time points once the problem solves successfully.
- If the solver reaches maximum iterations, try increasing from the default of 200 with something like: `m.options.MAX_ITER=500`. Increasing beyond 1000 rarely helps.

Comment: Thxs!!! It helped me a lot and I solved problem.